# Is it proper to use 'with' after 'initiating' in writing?

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to know if 'with' can be used after 'initiating'.
For example:

> There are many steps involved, initiating with A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not generally, no. In your example, you should say,

> “There are many steps involved, **beginning with** A”.

“Initiate” is not actually a synonym for “begin”, whatever some dictionaries may say.

Comment: 'Initiate' means '_cause_ something to begin', as in 'initiate a process'.